# How to correctly escape a % symbol

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

I'm having trouble getting a string URL to format correctly. The desired output is this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=corgi&start-index=1&max-results=50&v=2&fields=entry%5Blink/@rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007%23mobile'%5D
```

This is the code I started with:

```
NSString *urlRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=corgi&start-index=%u&max-results=%u&v=2&fields=entry[link/@rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007%23mobile']", dataStartIndex, dataIncrements];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlRequest];
```

It keeps garbling the '%23mobile' at the end and making it '20072obile'. I tried using a \ before the @ symbol but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Strangely, it works correctly if I break it into 2 pieces like this:

```
NSString *urlRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=corgi&start-index=%u&max-results=%u&v=2&fields=entry", dataStartIndex, dataIncrements];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlRequest stringByAppendingString:@"[link/@rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007%23mobile']"]];
```

It also works if I do it without any arguments (dataStartIndex, dataIncrements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `%23` with another `%`, to make `2007%%23mobile`.  For example:

```
NSString *urlRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=corgi&start-index=%u&max-results=%u&v=2&fields=entry[link/@rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007%%23mobile']", dataStartIndex, dataIncrements];
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra % to escape the %, since the string you provided is a format string, not plain string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :-

```
NSString *string=[@"yourUrlString" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```